# Closing a SocketChannel while doing a non-blocking read or write

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking, socketchannel

Are there any potential risks associated with closing a socket channel from another thread while it is performing continuous non-blocking read or write operations. Would I need to synchronize on the channnel object? Thanks.

Comment: This question may be related enough to be useful to you: [How to read SocketChannel in one thread, and write from n threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46874437/how-to-read-socketchannel-in-one-thread-and-write-from-n-threads)

Comment: So, the underlying OS would take into account my request to close the channel, even if it is busy doing other I/O? The mentioned post suggests this, but it is not exactly related to the actual closing of a channel.